# django unique if condition

Tags: django, database

i have the following state:

user A "took control" of resource R

i need to make sure that no one will have access on R until an ADMIN say

its o.k. to use it.

what i have now:

when a user take control of R i save a flag in the DB. (the flag is related to

R - if its True then R is taken)

the PROBLEM is that if 2 users try to get R at the same second there can be a

situation where the they both get R (because of thread timing).

how can i prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any code samples it's hard to answer your question precisely.

Nevertheless, I think you want something like this:

```
num_updated = Resource.objects.filter(id=1, is_taken=False).update(is_taken=True)
was_taken = (num_updated == 1)
```

This will create a single, atomic database query. If `is_taken` is `False`, it will be set to `True` and the return value will be 1. If the resource is already taken, though, no rows will match and the return value will be 0.

This should be free of race conditions (at least, it will be in PostgreSQL using the default *Read Committed* isolation level.)